# how to show in asp.net grid total rows and actual rows without slowing the performance

Tags: c#, asp.net

we have a asp.net1.1  3 tiers project in **production** .

right now for fetching data to asp.net grid, we have a constant call maxRows, and we don't fetch more than that (for performance reason).
we have a new request from the customer, "show me the num of total rows in the asp.net grid and the num of actual rows that have been fetch **for each grid in the project**."

between the presentation layer and the business layer we use .net remoting, and we are passing dataset between the tiers.

the database is ms sql server 2005.

we plan to upgrade this project to .net4.0

what is the solution for this request for .net1.1 and for .net4.0 ?

does asp.net grid have a built in feature to handle paging so we don't get outOfMemory exception for fetching a large amount of records ?

Comment: What did you try? You don't expect us to implement your customer's feature request for you, right? :)

Comment: You have also not told use anything about what database your using what data access tech your using what patterns your using.

Comment: "what is the solution for this request for .net1.1 and for .net4.0 ?" grid with events, properties,functions has been changed, see difference in msdn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to use CustomPaging.

It will show both the total number of rows in the dataset and you can fetch only the current page of grid and show it to the user:

Refer to the following documentation:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa713421%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
2. https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140032/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031506-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

two labels per grid.

```
num_of_rows_in_grid_label.Text = gridname.Rows.Count.ToString();
actual_num_of_rows_label.Text = datasourcename.Rows.Count.ToString();
```

(here datasourcename is a name of dataset, datatable or whatever u have there)

this is just a sample code to demonstrate logic, dunno what ur actual code looks like.